# Sql Injection Prevention and Converting Data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, sql-injection

I noticed in the Ruby on Rails Guide that this is considered correct format

```
Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])
```

whereas later on they used

```
Client.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date))
```

My question is, is it safe to assume that using the `.to_` method will be secure enough against sql injection?

Comment: They both end up going through the same code, AR replaces the placeholder on its own rather than using "real" placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that the to_ method will be secure, but that the format of:
where(:column => value) or with the new hash format: where(column: value) is just as secure and more convenient.